# Cloudfront signed cookies issue, getting 403

Tags: cookies, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

We have used CloudFront to store image URLs and using signed cookies to provide access only through our application. Without signed cookies we are able to access contents but after enabling signed cookies we are getting HTTP 403.

Below is configuration/cookies we are sending:

Cookies going with the request:

- `CloudFront-Expires: 1522454400`
- `CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id: xyz...`
- `CloudFront-Policy: abcde...`
- `CloudFront-Signature: abce...`

Here is our CloudFront policy:

```js
{
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Resource":"https://*.abc.com/*",
         "Condition":{
            "DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":1522454400}
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The cookie domain is `.abc.com`, and the resource path is `https://*.abc.com/*`.

We are using `CannedPolicy` to create `CloudFront` cookies.

Why isn't this working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I have got solution.Our requirement was wildcard access.

```
CloudFrontCookieSigner.getCookiesForCustomPolicy(
  this.resourcePath,
  pk,
  this.keyPairId,
  expiresOn,
  null,
  "0.0.0.0/0"
);
```

Where:

```
resource path = https+ "distribution name" + /*
      activeFrom = it is optional so pass it as null
      pk  = private key ( few api also take file but it didn't work, so get the private key from file and use above function)
```

we want to access all contents under distribution, canned policy doesn't allow wildcard. So, we changed it to custom policy and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this today or looking for clarification: You need to generate a **custom** policy if you would like to use wildcards in the resource url i.e. `https://mycdn.abc.com/protected-content-folder/*`

The AWS Cloudfront API has changed over the years; Currently, the easiest way to generate signed Cloudfront cookies or urls is via the AWS SDK, if available in your language of choice. Here is an example in NodeJS using the Javascriptv3 AWS SDK:

```js
const { getSignedCookies } = require("@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer");

// Read in your private_key.pem that you generated.
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./.secrets/private_key.pem", {
  encoding: "utf8",
});

const resource = `https://mycdn.abc.com/protected-content-folder/*`;
const dateLessThan = 1658593534;

const policyStr = JSON.stringify({
    Statement: [
      {
        Resource: resource,
        Condition: {
          DateLessThan: {
            "AWS:EpochTime": dateLessThan,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
});

const cfCookies = getSignedCookies({
  keyPairId,
  privateKey,
  policy: policyStr,
});

// Set CloudFront cookies using your web framework of choice
const cfCookieConfig = {
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
  sameSite: "lax",
  signed: false,
  expires: expiryDate,
  domain: ".abc.com",
};


for (let cookie in cfCookies) {
  ctx.cookies.set(cookie, cfCookies[cookie], { ...cfCookieConfig });
}
```

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html

Comment: Can you really set SameSite: Lax with CloudFront cookies? Your node server most likely runs on a different domain from the CloudFront distribution's domain (even when you customize it), which requires SameSite: None.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Yichun. I'm using a custom CloudFront distribution domain and my node server is running on a subdomain of that domain, hence why I can set Samesite: Lax. I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Review the documentation again

There are only 3 cookies, with the last being either `CloudFront-Expires` for a *canned* policy, or `CloudFront-Policy` for a *custom* policy.

> We are using CannedPolicy

A canned policy has an implicit resource of `*`, so a canned policy statement cannot have an explicit `Resource`, so you are in fact using a custom policy.  If all else is implemented correctly, your solution may simply be to remove the `CloudFront-Expires` cookie, which isn't used with a custom policy.

"Canned" (bottled, jugged, pre-packaged) policies are used in cases where the only unique information in the policy is the expiration.  Their advantage is that they require marginally less bandwidth (and make shorter URLs when creating signed URLs).  Their disadvantage is that they are wildcards by design, which is not always what you want.

Comment: Michael, we just need to prevent direct access of content with URL, so we thought to use signed cookies, so that content is accessible though application only. Moreover we are using canned policy only. If we send only three cookies : CloudFront-Expires: 1522454400,CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id: xyz..., CloudFront-Signature: abce... still we are getting 403. 
                                                               code :  this.signedCookies = CloudFrontCookieSigner.getCookiesForCannedPolicy(
    Protocol.https, this.domain, privateKeyFile, this.resourcePath, this.keyPairId, expiresOn);

Answer (score 0):

While there can be multiple reasons for 403 - AccessDenied as response. In our case, after debugging, we learnt that when using signed cookies - the **CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id** cookie remains same for every request while **CloudFront-Policy** and **CloudFront-Signature** cookies change values per request, otherwise 403 access denied will occur.